# Не получается изменить значение объекта в векторе C++

Tags: c++, vector, setter

Допустим, есть классы

```
class Class1
{
public:
   Class1(); 
   string getName();
   void setName(string);
   vector<Class2> getClasses2();
   void setClasses2(vector<Class>&);
private:
   string name;
   vector<Class2> classes2;
};
class Class2
{
public:
   Class2();
   string getName();
   void setName(string);
private:
   string name;
};
```

и реализации свойств:

```
vector<Class2> Class1::getClasses2()
{
    return classes2;
}
void Class1::setClasses2(vector<Class2> &value)
{
    classes2 = value;
}
string Class2::getName()
{
    return name;
}
void Class2::setName(string value)
{
    name = value;
}
```

Если в мейне попробовать изменить значение объекта вектора, то оно не меняется

```
Class1 cl1 = new Class1();//по дефолту заполняю класс, добавляю один элемент в вектор
cl1->getClasses2()[0].setName("NEW NAME");
```

Проходил отладчиком, в сеттере значение для name меняется, но после выхода из него всё остается прежним. Если просто создать в мейне

```
Class2 *pr1 = new Class2();
vector<Class2> vect;
vect.push_back(*pr1);
vect[0].setName("NEW NEW NAME");
```

то значение name меняется, что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша

```
vector<Class2> getClasses2();
```

возвращает *временную копию* вашего вектора из `Class1`. Именно в этой временной копии вы и делаете свои изменения. На оригинальный вектор эти изменения никак не влияют.

Comment: Спасибо, я как раз думал, что дело в чем то таком. Не подскажите, тогда как исправить ситуацию? Или придется таки делать вектора публичными?

Comment: @Alex: Ну "в лоб" ситуацию можно "исправить" просто вернув *ссылку* на вектор вместо копии вектора: `vector<Class2> &getClasses2();`. Однако это уже очень близко к публичному полю.